# How to force development mode Angular output error for non-existent properties?

Tags: angular, angular5, typescript2.0

I have an Angular 5 application generated through the Angular CLI. Suppose I have a component that contains the following markup:

```
<div *ngIf="dummyShowProp">
    <!-- other stuff here -->
</div>
```

#### Development mode

```
ng serve --hmr
```

If the component defines `dummyShowProp` it works fine. If the component does not define the property, the `div` is not shown and **no error is issued** (I assume that not declared property is evaluated to `falsy`)

#### Production build

```
ng build --prod
```

This fails (correctly IMO) with the following error:

> ERROR my.component.html(2,6): : Property 'dummyShowProp' does not
>   exist on type 'MyComponent'.

Production mode is more strict than development mode, but I cannot find how to force this check also in development mode.

Relevant configuration below:

#### package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Question:** How to force development mode Angular output error for non-existent properties?

Comment: You can enable AOT (--aot) for development which should generate any errors related to the compilation of the templates. Please note this will significantly increase rebuild times.
`ng server --aot`

Answer (score 0):

use the command `ng build --env=prod`.

with `ng build --env=prod` you do not achieve AOT compilation, for more details see docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files

Comment: My issue is not receiving an error while maintaining the server via `ng serve --hmr` (during development). I know that production builds performs additional verifications and I am interested in how to issue the same property not found error during development.

Comment: Iin the `ng-build` aot is default turned on. but ng server we have to force it on. try using  `ng serve --aot`

Comment: But the fallback is `ng serve --aot` causes constant rebuild

Comment: I have tried `ng serve --hmr --aot` (and also without hmr), but I receive `Runtime compiler is not loaded`. I think what I look for is `fullTemplateTypeCheck ` which seems [to have some issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21733). I will dig more and come back.